# How to simplify lengthy symbolic expressons in SymPy

Tags: sympy, simplify

I  have been working on some integrations and even though the system is working, it takes much more time to work than it should.

The problem is that the expressions are many pages, and even though they are 3 variables only, sy.simplify just crashes the Kernel after 4 hours or so.

Is there a way to make such lengthy expressions more compact?

EDIT:

Trying to recreate a test expression, using `cse`. I can't really substitute the symbols to make a final expression, equal to the 1st one

```
sy.var('a:c x')
testexp = sp.log(x)+a*(0.5*x)**2+(b*(0.5*x)**2+b+sp.log(x))/c
r, e = sy.cse(testexp)
FinalFunction = sy.lambdify(r[0:][0]+(a,b,c,x),e[0])
Points = sy.lambdify((a,b,c,x),r[0:][1])
FinalFunction(Points(1,1,1,1),1,1,1,1)

>>>NameError: name 'x1' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cse(expr)` is sometimes a way to get a more compact representation since repeated subexpressions can be replaced with a single symbol. `cse` returns a list of repeated expressions and a list of expressions (a singleton if you only passed a single expression):

```
>>> from sympy import solve
>>> var('a:c x');solve(a*x**2+b*x+c, x)
(a, b, c, x)
[(-b + sqrt(-4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a), -(b + sqrt(-4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a)]
>>> r, e = cse(_)
>>> for i in r: pprint(Eq(*i))
...
        _____________
       ╱           2
x₀ = ╲╱  -4⋅a⋅c + b
      1
x₁ = ───
     2⋅a
>>> for i in e: pprint(i)
...
x₁⋅(-b + x₀)
-x₁⋅(b + x₀)
```

You are still going to have long expressions but they will be represented more compactly (and more efficiently for computatation) if `cse` is able to identify repeated subexpressions.

To use this in SymPy you can create two Lambdas: one to translate the variables into the replacement values and the other to use those values:

```
>>> v = (a,b,c,x)
>>> Pts = Lambda(v, tuple([i[1] for i in r]+list(v)))
>>> Pts(1,2,3,4)
(2*sqrt(2)*I, 1/2, 1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> Func = Lambda(tuple([i[0] for i in r]+list(v)), tuple(e))
>>> Func(*Pts(1,2,3,4))
(-1 + sqrt(2)*I, -1 - sqrt(2)*I)
```

Comment: the result it gives, is not an expression. Is there documentation for this command? It gives arrays with 'x_i' etc. (sorry for delayed answer)

Comment: Actually I found the documentation, although I dont think it returns an expression somehow?

Comment: Sorry for commenting again. But in my understanding I need to "define" more expressions, to be exact, a list of expressions equal to the length of `r` in order to  have a final expressions, that, using the previous ones, will be "easier" to evaluate than the original "lonely" expression. Am I correct? Also, IF you can see the edit, I tried to calculate it, and it doesn't let me substitute the values of `r`.

Comment: Guess I'm being too annoying. Sorry for bothering you!

Comment: No problem. I don't often do what you are trying to do. I updated the answer for how I would do this with Lambda

Comment: Oh. Really thank you again. and for the previous questions too